# Getting all words and punctiation from English text

Tags: ruby, nlp, text-analysis

What I want to do:

User loads the text. I analyse it and get all words and punctuation from it. Now I can easy render text for other users with fast translation of each word or additional info of analysed words.

Now I'm trying to use [treat](https://github.com/louismullie/treat) gem(NLP for ruby) but there are many problems with it.

For example in sentence

"The world ain't all sunshine and rainbows."

It divides ain't in two words "ai" and "n't"

Can anybody suggest some libraries or gem, maybe which I can implement with jruby where I can just separate text in words and punctuations without problems.

Or mb I'm wrong in my ideas and there is any other ways?

Comment: I corrected my mistakes. Sorry for that. English is not my native language.

Comment: As a note, "ain't" isn't actually an English word, but slang. If it's just that (and possibly other contractions) you're having problems with, that might shed some light on where to start making changes.

Comment: I see but user can load text with slang also. And this is the point to analyse it correctly.

Comment: Tell me whats your definition of a word according to you. if its something which is separated by <space>, then you can use text.split(" ")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not start from a simple scan, where you use a simple regular expression to get all words from the text? http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-scan

For English, the regular expression should be simply \w, and some special characters like the ' you indicate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [open-nlp](https://github.com/louismullie/open-nlp) gem from the same author?

An example there suggests it does what you want:

```
OpenNLP.load

text      = "The death of the poet was kept from his poems."
tokenizer = OpenNLP::SimpleTokenizer.new
tokens    = tokenizer.tokenize(text).to_a
# => %w[The death of the poet was kept from his poems .]
```

Unfortunately, since I don't have `jruby` on my machine right now I couldn't confirm it's working as expected for cases with words with apostrophes.